# JBPM - Custom Editor for Custom Work Item Property

Tags: drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor

I have defined a custom work-item for Email task/activity in JBPM with **.wid** file.

One of the property "**Mail Body**" requires a rich-text or text-area for editing.

I know that in **.wid** file we have to set **customEditor** property mapping it to a editor.

Is it possible to use an existing editor for this ?

Ex. The Script task has a rich-text editor for it "Script" property.

Can I use that Script editor for my custom work-item's property ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with drools-guvnor, I assume this is related to the web-based Designer, not the Eclipse-based one?  The custom editor is something that is currently only supported in Eclipse.

In Designer, you can currently register custom editors for specific properties:http://surdilovic.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/custom-input-editors-in-jbpm-designer/

Support for custom editors as you describe will be available in the next version.

Kris

Comment: Thank you Kris. Let me try to follow the blog and use this great feature.

Comment: "in the next version" and this answer is almost 5 years old. Update?